# Getting my rails application to recognize coffeescript?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a rails application and I am trying to add event handlers with coffeescript.

I am simply trying to recognize a click event occurring within a div (class="subjects") element, in app/views/users/show.html.erb

I have, in the corresponding app/assets/javascripts/users.coffee file, the following:

```
$(document).on "page:change", ->
  $('.subjects').click ->
    alert "CLICK"
```

Yet when I click on the div, nothing happens. It seems like the coffeescript and view are not communicating correctly, but I do not know how to resolve the problem.

How can I incorporate the coffeescript to be recognized by the show.html.erb file?

Comment: does page:change event get triggered? Any errors in browser console?

Comment: how can I check that an event is triggered?

Comment: by adding alert or console log in it or setting a breakpoint

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Turbolinks 5 (from Rails 5) then `page:change` will not fire.

To remedy this you can use `turbolinks:load`.

Example:

```
$(document).on "turbolinks:load", ->
  $('.subjects').click ->
    alert "CLICK"
```